# What is the QED model about half wave plate?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, helicity

Surely classical electrodynamics (CED) has a good and well-known answer about the change of light polarization in a HWP (or Quarter wave plate). I tried to find how does this look like from point of view of QED but couldn't find anything by googling. And nevertheless as QED is a superior to CED theory it must somehow explain it. For QED an interaction of the photon changes its helicity abruptly from +1 to -1 (left to right polarization or vice versa). How this fact can explain the length of the plate?

Comment: I prepared a presentation for our quantum computing theory group a few months ago to show them how the unitary operators relate to actual physical devices, and the classical intuition. I can produce the actual matrix if it helps. I actually rotate the polarization in the lab, one photon at a time, and then count them, when taking Bell state measurements.

Answer (score 1):

A wave plate is a passive component, and can be modelled as a unitary operator on the quantum state. The state is a superposition of left and right circular polarized photons, and the operator gradually alters the relative phases. The total distance then determines the final polarization state.

Comment: My question obviously need some better description.  Maybe my understanding of an interaction of a photon with ciral molecules is wrong. Lets have a photon with helicity +1. I think that after absorption the molecule emits just a photon with helicity -1. If this is so I can not understand what is the meaning of path of lambda/2. But it looks as if the photon is released within a superposition state alfa(+1)+beta(-1). If so there is no problem,

Comment: Since a wave plate is transparent, essentially lossless, and can transit an image, we can safely conclude that photons are not absorbed and emitted; if they were absorbed the emission follows at a random time later, related to the excited state lifetime,  and in a random direction. Thus the process is forward coherent scattering.  The crystal medium is homogeneous but not isotropic;  this leads to interference effects which preferentially rotate the plane of polarization as the media is traversed.

Comment: You are quite right. I didnt think about this. But what is the Feynmann diagram then? I have the impression that every Feynmann diagram involves absorption and emission?

Comment: Scattering;  sometimes described as a virtual absorption/emission. Coherence must be maintained.

Comment: So it is out of time then? If so it can not be a physical process.

Comment: Out of time?  What do you mean?  Feynman give's a layman's explanation in "QED: the strange theory of light and matter".  For a [textbook treatment](https://books.google.com/books?id=7GqHpAqYiwIC&lpg=PA367&ots=X_iTvjrDGm&dq=feynman%20diagram%20for%20photon%20scattering%20forward%20coherent&pg=PA367#v=onepage&q=feynman%20diagram%20for%20photon%20scattering%20forward%20coherent&f=false) try this one.

Comment: You wrote "if they were absorbed the emission follows at a random time later, related to the excited state lifetime, and in a random direction." Then it is normaly to conclude that virtual absorption /emition does not take time. But I think Feynman diagrams are considered by many as a mathematical  instument only.

Comment: That is just basic atomic physics for absorption and emission - that is what we observe. Surely you agree that this is the case?

Comment: Of course I agree that real emission absorption takes time. Exactly as you said that emission follows at random times (absolutely) and in random direction (that is not really true if there is interference of the wavefuntion like in reflection). Than it follows that there is no real absorption/emission - just virtual is what is observed, which is accomplished in no time, as not have a phase lag.